# How to plot density of states (DOS) using histogram

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, physics

I want to plot density of states (DOS) using histogram. DOS is defined as the number of states in the unit interval of energy `$dN/dE$`. I have energy values. DOS graph is plotted b/w Energy (on x-axis) and DOS (on y-axis). Units of DOS are 1/Energy. Histograms are unitless but I want to get units of 1/Energy on the y-axis. If I divide counts (of each bin) by their respective bin width, can I get units of 1/energy in case of histogram?

```
E = np.array([-1.61032636, -1.23577245, -0.50587484, -0.28348457, 
              -0.18748945,  0.4537447,   1.2338455,   2.13535718])

n,bins, patches = plt.hist(E, bins=4)
print("n: ", n)
print("bins: ", bins)
plt.savefig("./DOS")
```

Comment: Can you show the content of  `e` and `d` ?

Comment: e is the energy  eigenvalues which I have given by name Data but I'm not sue about e.I want to know how to plot  DOS it by histogram

Comment: Can you explain more precisely what you want to plot ? (`e` and `d`or `Data` ?) Or what are the errors ? The 2 last pieces of code works.

Comment: I want to plot Data on x-axis and DOS on y-axis. But DOS is defied as no of available states in a unit volume. We can plot DOS using histogram. But I;m not sure how to calculate y-axis. Y axis counts no of states available in each bin. But DOS is defied as 1/E/V. So I'm not sure how can we plot it

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that you are well able to plot a normal histogram, where the y-axis gives the counts per bin, but what you'd like to do is make a plot where the height of a bin is scaled by the width of the bin (I've seen these kinds of "dN/dE" plots in Radiation Detection and Measurement when you're looking at a differential pulse height spectrum from a pulse height analyzer).

One way to achieve this is to, as you mentioned, divide the number of counts by the bin width, and then to try "treating each bin as a single point with a weight equal to its count" (https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html) divided by the binwidth:

```
# After you get n and bins from the original histogram
binwidth = bins[1] - bins[0]
plt.hist(bins[:-1], bins, weights=n/binwidth)
```

The other option is to weight *each count* by 1/binwidth:

```
weight = 1/binwidth
weights = [weight] * len(E)  # Makes a list of len(E) copies of weight
plt.hist(E,bins=bins,weights=weights)
```

It's six one way and half-dozen the other.

Answer (score 0):

When you decide to draw an histogram, you want to plot all the values contained in an interval. If I well understand, you want to count all the `e` values according to the `Data` list. If you're not clear with that, have a look [here](https://statistics.laerd.com/statistical-guides/understanding-histograms.php).

`Data` will define in which interval you want to count the `e` values. The `bin` parameter [(doc)](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html) gives you this possibility. 
It's also "better" to sort the data. If you do not sort the `Data`, that means that intervals can overlap and you could count values in several intervals. (If you don't sort it, it works. I'm not sure this is what you want, depends on your work). Here, I sorted the `Data`. You can try both !

Here an example:

```
# Import module
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
Data = np.array([-1.61032636, -1.23577245, -0.50587484, -0.28348457,
                 -0.18748945, 0.4537447, 1.2338455, 2.13535718])
Data.sort()
print(Data)
# [-1.61032636 - 1.23577245 - 0.50587484 - 0.28348457 - 0.18748945  0.4537447
#   1.2338455    2.13535718]

# Just in order you get the same plot
np.random.seed(2019)
# Assuming e is define as bellow
e = (np.random.rand(50) - 0.5) * 2
print(e)
# [ 0.80696443 -0.21383899  0.24793992  0.2757548   0.76099814 -0.40165596
#   0.40439654  0.80641232  0.76276385 -0.1885004  -0.09510676 -0.46585935
#  -0.67427026  0.77842939 -0.70304755  0.96944697 -0.93527756  0.03070151
#  -0.59774191  0.77202175  0.02723984  0.15660317 -0.40143469  0.67439481
#   0.05329966 -0.79031152 -0.44374118 -0.90681013  0.0181523  -0.05514742
#   0.80897467  0.88698444  0.4067847   0.69259591  0.85598929  0.63872377
#   0.69037113  0.58290375 -0.65799968 -0.42004416 -0.39103217 -0.70467981
#   0.14763706  0.72711402 -0.35340105 -0.44870115  0.36437477 -0.61718738
#   0.16204896  0.72511654]


# Build the histogram
n, bins, patches = plt.hist(e, bins=Data )

print("n: ", n)
print("bins: ", bins)

# Show the histogram
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Actually DOS demands unit interval of energy. Units on y-axis should be 1/E. It shouldn't be counts

Comment: Is it an histogram you want ?

Comment: yes I want histogram.But y-axis should have 1/E units

Comment: It's a non-sense to plot `1/E` since you draw an histogram. You're counting the number of values in each interval so that can not be a float.

Comment: I'm sure that it can be plotted using histogram. Data(has units in energy). Can I divide counts by bin-size to get 1/E units

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you're looking for. Please, edit your question with clearer explications and showing what is there in `e` variable.

Comment: @jerry the value of a histogram bin corresponds to the **integral** of `dn/dE` over its corresponding range of `E`, so the Y-axis should be *dimensionless* (i.e. integer state counts) – so there is nothing wrong with `Alexandre B.`'s answer.

Comment: y-axis measures count(and is dimensionless). absolutely right. What if I divide count by bin width? Can I get 1/E units on y-axis?

Comment: Yes by doing that you get the *mean values* of `dn/dE` over the ranges of each bin.